# Kendo layouts not rendering widgets without setTimeout

Tags: mvvm, frameworks, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I upgraded the kendo library to the 2014Q1 framework which had a few nice features that they were adding, however when I did that it broke any widget (grid, tabStrip, select lists, etc.) from rendering at all. I tracked it down to the layout/view not being able to activate the widget without being wrapped in a setTimeout set to 0. Am I missing something key here or did I build this thing in an invalid way?

http://jsfiddle.net/upmFf/

The basic idea of the problem I am having is below (remove the comments and it works):

```
var router = new kendo.Router();
var mainLayout = new kendo.Layout($('#mainLayout').html());
var view = new kendo.View('sample', {
     wrap: false,
     model: kendo.observable({}),
     init: function() {
          // setTimeout(function(){
              $("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker();
          // }, 0);
     }
 });

 mainLayout.render('#container');

 router.route('/', function() {
     mainLayout.showIn('#app', view);
 });

 router.start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admittedly, I don't fully understand it, but hope this helps.

Basically when you try to init the `#datepicker`, the view elements have not been inserted into the DOM yet. You can put a breakpoint inside the init function, when it hits, check the DOM and you will see that the `#app` is an empty div, and `#datepicker` does not exist yet (at least not on the DOM).

`kendo.Layout.showIn` seems to need to exit in order for the view to finish rendering, but when it initializes the view's elements, it thinks the render is done and init is triggered incorrectly ahead of time. The `setTimeout` works because it runs the kendoDatePicker initialization asynch, the view is able to finish rendering before the timeout function.

**Workarounds...**

Trigger the view rendering from the view object itself:

```
var view = new kendo.View('sample', {
    init: function() {
        $("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker();
    }
});
router.route('/', function() {
    view.render('#app');
});
```

Select and find the datepicker from the view object itself:

```
var view = new kendo.View('sample', {
    init: function() {
        view.element.find("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker();        
    }
});
router.route('/', function() {
    mainLayout.showIn('#app', view);
});
```

Near the bottom of [this thread](http://www.telerik.com/forums/initialization-of-two-kendo-widgets-in-different-pages) is where I got the idea for the 2nd option. Maybe someone else can come around and give a better explanation of whats going on.

Comment: Yes I agree with you I did run a bunch of tests that concluded the same, the element does not exist until one of the above solutions is implemented or using `data-role="datepicker"`. I do like the `view.element.find` approach however like the setTimeout or using data-role to init the item is a bandaid solution at best when the layout should be handling this for us like in the 2013 libs: http://jsfiddle.net/k2PWB/ . I would settle for something like calling a super at the top of the init to ensure that the init setup code runs fully.

Comment: @JakeTheBraek Agreed, this is a bandaid solution at best, unless if this was an intended breaking change. Another weird thing I found was that, the documentation claims that Layout.ShowIn will trigger the `show` event of the kendo.View. So I tried to init the datepicker in the show event, but it doesn't even hit the event.

Comment: Yeah saw that too, I assumed it was at the same level as the init method, threw it in and couldn't get it to call, same with hide as you might imagine. It seems the whole layout manager mechanism is a bit of an afterthought at best. Hopefully when my company starts paying for the full license I can get some answer to these questions in a more formal capacity. I do appreciate your help though @gitsitgo it is always nice to know that I am not going crazy :)